# Tiling the plane with mutually non-congruent equal area rectangles

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling

Question: Is it possible to tile the plane with mutually non-congruent rectangles all of equal area?

Note 1: If the answer is "yes" then, there could be constrained versions of the question regarding upper and lower bounds that could be applied to the length to width ratio.

Note 2: Analogous questions can be asked with "perimeter" and "length of diagonal" replacing "area".

Ref: This question was once recorded (alongside some related thoughts) https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2016/06/non-congruent-tiling-ongoing-story.html